# Gaussian Kernel confirmation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement this kernel function[image]

which is also known as radial basis function. Suppose that `a = 2`, `b = 1` and `σ = 150`.

- Xi is a 425x3 matrix
- Xj is a 4x3 matrix

I've came up with this code but I'm not sure that is correct. Can you help me?

```
kS = exp( - (pdist2(Xj,Xi).^2) / (sigma^2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: the original answer was completely redefined, because I misinterpreted the definition of the problem.

The evaluation of the kernel distance between `Xi` and `Xj` is presented below. Two codes that implement the algorithm are presented. The first code is inefficient but can be easily related to the definition of the kernel distance. The second code is much more efficient, but may not be as clear due to several vectorisation tricks.

The code assumes the following interpretation of the problem:

1. `Xi` and `Xj` are 2 data sets that contain 425 and 4 points, respectively. Each point belongs to `R^3` (real vector space with dimension 3).
2. The kernel distance between two data sets is calculated according to the definition given in the article by J.M. Phillips and S. Venkatasubramanian "A Gentle Introduction to the Kernel Distance" that can be found at the following [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1625v2.pdf). The definition is also provided below:

---

[image]

---

The most straightforward implementation of the algorithm:

```
% Initialisation.
clear;
clc;

% Construct Xi.
Xi = [randn(425, 1) randn(425, 1) randn(425, 1)];

% Definition of Xj.
Xj = [0.1 0.2 0.3; 0 0 0; -0.1 -0.1 -0.2; 1 -8 4];

% Convert to cell arrays.
Xi = mat2cell(Xi, ones(1, length(Xi(:, 1))), 3);
Xj = mat2cell(Xj, ones(1, length(Xj(:, 1))), 3);

% First, construct the kernel function for the evaluation of individual
% points in Xi and Xj
omega = 150;
a = 2;
kerFunction = @(xi, xj) exp(sum(abs(xi - xj).^a)/(omega^2));

kerDist = 0;
for i = 1 : length(Xj)
    for j = 1 : length(Xj)
        kerDist = kerDist + kerFunction(Xj{i}, Xj{j});
    end
end
for i = 1 : length(Xi)
    for j = 1 : length(Xi)
        kerDist = kerDist + kerFunction(Xi{i}, Xi{j});
    end
end
for i = 1 : length(Xi)
    for j = 1 : length(Xj)
        kerDist = kerDist - 2*kerFunction(Xi{i}, Xj{j});
    end
end
```

---

A more efficient implementation of the algorithm is presented below:

```
clear;

% Define constants.
omega = 150;
a = 2;

% Definition of Xi.
Xi = [randn(425, 1) randn(425, 1) randn(425, 1)];

% Definition of Xj.
Xj = [0.1 0.2 0.3; 0 0 0; -0.1 -0.1 -0.2; 1 -8 4];

% Definition of the characteristics of the data sets.
numPointsXj = length(Xj(:, 1));
numPointsXi = length(Xi(:, 1));

% Define a handle function for the definition of indices for the
% vectorisation of the kernel function.
hdlRepIdxPermutation = @(numPoints, numMatrixRep) ...
    repmat( ...
    (1 : numPoints : numPoints*(numMatrixRep - 1) + 1)', ...
    1, numPoints ...
    ) + ...
    repmat(0 : (numPoints - 1), numMatrixRep, 1);

tic

% Calculate the term that corresponds to K(p, p') in the definition of the
% kernal distance.
repXiRight = repmat(Xi, numPointsXi, 1);
leftIdxPermutationXi = hdlRepIdxPermutation(numPointsXi, numPointsXi);
repXiLeft = repXiRight(leftIdxPermutationXi(:), :);

kerDistComp1 = sum(exp(sum(abs(repXiLeft - repXiRight).^a, 2)/(omega^2)));

% Calculate the term that corresponds to K(q, q') in the definition of the
% kernal distance.
repXjRight = repmat(Xj, numPointsXj, 1);
leftIdxPermutationXj = hdlRepIdxPermutation(numPointsXj, numPointsXj);
repXjLeft = repXjRight(leftIdxPermutationXj(:), :);

kerDistComp2 = sum(exp(sum(abs(repXjLeft - repXjRight).^a, 2)/(omega^2)));

% Calculate the term that corresponds to K(p, q) in the definition of the
% kernal distance.
repXjRight = repmat(Xj, numPointsXi, 1);
repXiLeft = repmat(Xi, numPointsXj, 1);
leftIdxPermutationXi = hdlRepIdxPermutation(numPointsXi, numPointsXj);
repXiLeft = repXiLeft(leftIdxPermutationXi(:), :);
kerDistComp3 = -2*sum(exp(sum(abs(repXiLeft - repXjRight).^a, 2)/(omega^2)));

kerDist = kerDistComp1 + kerDistComp2 + kerDistComp3;

toc

disp(kerDist);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem i'm trying to solve is to calculate the kernelized distance between two patterns with the above function. In real space the distance between two patterns can be calculated by euclidean distance for example. But we need a kernelized distance metric if we map data to high dimensional space. I'm not sure that the above script does what I want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I might have misinterpreted your question. However, I would appreciate if you could explain your question a little bit further. What exactly do you mean by a "kernelized distance metric"? Does it agree with the definition of the kernel distance provided at this [link](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/papers/gentleintroKD.pdf) (eq. 1.1)?

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. If we don't map data to a higher dimension then the distance between two patterns can be calculated easily. So, the kernelized distance is given by:

Comment: || φ(Xi) - φ(Xj) ||.^2 = K(Xi,Xi) + K(Xj,Xj) - 2K(Xi,Xj). Clearly for gaussian kernel, K(Xi,Xi) = 1 and thus the above relation reduces to : d(Xi,Xj) = || φ(Xi) - φ(Χj) ||^2 = 2 * (1 - K(Xi,Xj)). This is the kernelized distance metric which i'm trying to implement. Thank you.

Comment: I am not certain if I fully understand your interpretation of X_i and X_j, as opposed to x_(i,k) and x_(j,k) in the definition of the kernel. My (new) interpretation of the problem is that X_i and X_j are two data sets. X_i has 425 points, X_j has 4 points (each point belongs to R^3). You need to calculate the kernel distance between these 2 sets of points. The reason why I think this is the case is that the sum in the definition of the kernel is iterated over k, but not i and j. In this case your definition of  d(Xi,Xj) is only applicable to individual points, but not the entire data sets.

Comment: I posted the answer based on the assumptions stated in the comments above. The code is merely a sketch, as I am still not certain whether I interpreted the problem in the most appropriate way. If the code does what you need, let me know and I will try to improve readability and efficiency.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the code and I  will let you known as soon as possible.